Send email from Gmail using Excel VBA
I have 4 accounts set in my Outlook desktop app and I want so send emails preferably from email #4 which is a gmail.
I've tried using both SendUsingAccount and SentOnBehalfOfName and neither worked.
When I try
    With OutlookMail
        .SendUsingAccount = OutlookApp.Session.Accounts.Item("me@gmail.com")
        .To = Cells(17, 46).Value
        .Subject = "Test Macro"
        .Attachments.Add "C:\Formação em Dados\Grafico e analise Dinamica.pdf"
        .Body = "Test"
        .Send
    End With

The email is sent but from my first or main account set in the app, which is me@outlook.com. Same thing happens with .Sender instead of .SendUsingAccount
If I replace ("me@gmail.com") for (4) I get an error saying the index is out of range.
If I try SentOnBehalfOfName, nothing happens, the email isn't even sent at all.
Important info: I've ran a code that reports the index for each account and it only shows the first one. I do have all of them configured in the app.

You need to use Set with .SendUsingAccount.
Is this what you are trying?
Option Explicit

Sub SendEmailFromGmail()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    
    '~~> Create Outlook application object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    '~~> Create a new mail item
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
         
    '~~> Set email properties
    With OutlookMail
        Set .SendUsingAccount = OutlookApp.Session.Accounts.Item("me@gmail.com")
         
        .Subject = "Your Subject"
        .Body = "Your Email Body"
        .To = "ToSomeone@hotmail.com"
        
        '~~> Display
        .Display
    End With
    
    '~~> Clean up
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub


Sorry for taking so long to respond. The code you posted didn't work because I get an error saying the argument is invalid on line
Set .SendUsingAccount = OutlookApp.Session.Accounts.Item("me@gmail.com")
If I replace the email for an index, I get that error saying index is out of range

I tried complementing it with
For Each mailAccount In OutlookApp.Session.Accounts             If mailAccount.DisplayName = "me@gmail.com" Then                 Set .SendUsingAccount = mailAccount                 Exit For             End If
But again, it sends the email but only from my main account.

Strange, it works for me. I have 3 email addresses in my Outlook and it worked each time I changed it.
